# How would I free a pointer malloc'd in a separate function?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2012, malloc, free

I have a global variable called exam which is of type struct Exam:

```
typedef struct 
{
    Question* phead;
}Exam;

Exam exam;
```

In a function I malloc space for the pointer phead:

```
int initExam()
{
    exam.phead = malloc(sizeof(Question*));
    exam.phead = NULL;

    return 1;
}
```

In a separate function I try to free this memory:

```
void CleanUp()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    Question* currentQuestion = exam.phead;

    while (currentQuestion != NULL) {
        // some other code
    }
    exam.phead = NULL;
}
```

I have also tried the following inside my function:

```
free(exam.phead);
```

My issue is it does not seem to free the memory allocated by malloc. I would like CleanUp() to free up the memory allocated by exam.phead and I cannot change the function signatures or move the free() calls to another function. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to C programming. Thanks!

Comment: You're setting `exam.phead` to `NULL` right after allocating it in `initExam`. That's a straight memory leak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free memory allocated in a different function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071190/free-memory-allocated-in-a-different-function)

Comment: You don't free pointers, you free the things they point to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak, right from the off:

```
int initExam()
{
    exam.phead = malloc(sizeof(Question*));//assign address of allocated memory
    exam.phead = NULL;//reassign member, to a NULL-pointer

    return 1;
}
```

the `exam.phead` member is assigned the address of the memory you allocated, only to become a null-pointer right after. A null pointer can be `free`'d safely, but it doesn't *do* anything.
Meanwhile, the `malloc`'ed memory will stay allocated, but you have no pointer to it, and therefore cannot manage it. You can't `free` the memory, nor can you use it. I take it the `NULL` assignment is an attempt to initialize the memory to a *"clean"* value. There are ways to to this, which I'll get to in a moment.

Anyway, because `phead` is NULL, the following statements:

```
Question* currentQuestion = exam.phead;//is the same as currentQuestion = NULL;
while (currentQuestion != NULL) //is the same as while(0)
```

don't make sense, at all.

***To initialize*** newly allocated memory, either use `memset`, or `calloc`. The latter initializes the allocated block of memory to zero, `memset` can do this do (`calloc` is basically the same as calling `malloc` + `memset`), but allows you to initialize to any value you like:

```
char *foo = calloc(100, sizeof *foo);// or calloc(100, 1);
//is the same as writing:
char *bar = malloc(100);
memset(bar, '\0', 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `exam.phead` in `initExam` to `NULL` right after you allocate memory with `malloc`. [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)  doesn't do anything with a `NULL` pointer so you're leaking memory.